# In FirebirdSql, how to return exception message from procedure

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, firebird2.1

I want to return the error message from a procedure when an exception happens.  In SQL Server you would select the Error_Number() and Error_Message().  How would I do it in FirebirdSql

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE sprocname
 ( id int ) 
RETURNS 
 ( gcode int, errmsg varchar(250) )
AS 
BEGIN
  gcode = 0;
  errmsg = '';
  -- do procedure code here


  WHEN ANY DO
  BEGIN 
    gcode = gdscode; -- ??
    errmsg = ??;
  END
  SUSPEND;
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Comment: You could simply not catch the exception, it will bubble to the caller.

Comment: I want to format the message and error code.  Its for an intranet web app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need to do that at the client side, as it is currently not possible to obtain this in PSQL. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/947) in the Firebird tracker, which has been implemented for Firebird 4, which is expected to be released in 2019.

See [Firebird 4 release notes, section *System Function RDB$ERROR()*](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/4_0/rlsnotes40.html#rnfb40-psql-rdb-error):

> The function `RDB$ERROR()` takes a PSQL error context as input and
> returns the specific context of the active exception. Its scope is
> confined to the context of the exception-handling block in PSQL.
> Outside the exception handling block, `RDB$ERROR` always contains
> `NULL`.
>
> The type of the return value depends on the context.
>
> Syntax Rules
>
> ```
> RDB$ERROR ( context )
> context ::= { GDSCODE | SQLCODE | SQLSTATE | EXCEPTION | MESSAGE }
> ```
>
> [..]
>
> Example
>
> ```
> BEGIN
>   ...
> WHEN ANY DO
>   EXECUTE PROCEDURE P_LOG_EXCEPTION(RDB$ERROR(MESSAGE));
> END
> ```

Comment: Well, I sure wish your's wasn't the correct answer, but since it is, for now, I'm going to give you credit for it

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADD_COUNTRY (
    ACountryName COUNTRYNAME,
    ACurrency VARCHAR(10) )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO country (country,
                       currency)
  VALUES (:ACountryName,
          :ACurrency);
  WHEN ANY DO
  BEGIN
        -- write an error in log
    IN AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION DO
      INSERT INTO ERROR_LOG (PSQL_MODULE,
                             GDS_CODE,
                             SQL_CODE,
                             SQL_STATE)
      VALUES ('ADD_COUNTRY',
              GDSCODE,
              SQLCODE,
              SQLSTATE);
    -- Re-throw exception
    EXCEPTION;
  END
END
```

http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-handleexceptions.html