# How do I get the text associated with a Firebird SQL exception in a "when any" block?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have the following in a Firebird (version 2.1) stored procedure. When an exception occurs I get the GDSCODE and the SQLCODE but I can't figure how to get the descriptive error message text that goes with the error. Is it possible to do so? Is there a variable like SQLERRORTEXT or some such? My search of Google has not turned up any.

```
  begin
    insert into BOOKING_STATUS (status_id, description) values ("test1", "test1");      
    when any do begin
      error_code = 1;
      error_message = "Error inserting booking_status. Error: " || GDSCODE || " " || SQLCODE;
      suspend;
      exit; 
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in your version of firebird. Take a look at [this request](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-2040).

It turns out that this facility is present in Firebird 4.0+.

---

Similar questions:

[In FirebirdSql, how to return exception message from procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555143/in-firebirdsql-how-to-return-exception-message-from-procedure)

[Firebird - handling exception's custom-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300842/firebird-handling-exceptions-custom-message)